# How to set cursor in CSS from image collection

Tags: css

Let's say i have images.png file where i have stored 24x24 cursors.

How to do something like that:

`background: url(images.png);
background-position: -24px -24px;`

using cursor property. I need to set a cursor which's properties should look like something like this:

Cursor width: 24px;

Cursor height: 24px;

Background position for cursor: -24px -24px.

Should i create a div element which will have cursor background and will move when user moves cursor?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The cursor property also takes a url function

```
div {
   cursor: url(cursor1.svg) 4 4
}
```

Comment: Yes, but that won’t be enough here for this case, where they want to use a PNG image as a “sprite”. The x/y coordinates you can specify here are only used to determine the part of the image that is supposed to be the “tip” of the cursor, but you can _not_ use them in the same way as background-position to display only part of a sprite image.

Comment: u need js for this, check this https://codepen.io/storm11/pen/pZXxBB change the circle the way you want (put image and stuff) and use cursor:none in place of cusor:corsshair